# Link from .env item is destroyed in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables

Sorry for my bad English.

I have these entries in the .env file:

```
VUE_APP_REST_API_URL=http://192.168.1.57:8080/rest/web
VUE_APP_RESOURCE_LOGIN=token
```

In the component Login.vue I have this code:

```
const url = path.join (process.env.VUE_APP_REST_API_URL, process.env.VUE_APP_RESOURCE_LOGIN);
console.log (url);
this.axios.post(url, formdata)
```

Console.log outputs this:
Login.vue? 7463: 95 **http:/192.168.1.57:8080/rest/web/token**
why is one of two slashes removed? does an url need to be escaped?

Comment: [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) is a NodeJS API which you should avoid using in your components since they run in the browser. Just use string concatenation

Comment: Also, `path` is used for working with filesystem paths, not URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another way to do this, and i prefer this one in template generated with vue-cli

```js
const url = `${process.env.VUE_APP_REST_API_URL}/${process.env.VUE_APP_RESOURCE_LOGIN}`
```

don't get disturbed with one solution if you have two or more option.

Comment: Many many thanks. It works perfectly.
Have a nice day.